# How to make intersection between method

Tags: java, intersection

The output of my code is:

```
The fibonacci list that smaller than 40 is:
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 
The prime list that smaller than 40 is:
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37
```

I want to make an intersection between these two list.

To make it becomes: (when I put variable n=40 in fibo() and allPrime() method)

```
2 3 5 13
```

But I don't know how to do this. I've searched the forum, and most of the intersection question is between two arraylist or two sets.

I've wonder if it's possible to make intersection between two function like this?

```
public class FiboAndPrime {

    static boolean IsPrime(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Find all the prime numbers that are less than or equal to n
    static void allPrime(int n) {
        for(int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
            if(IsPrime(i)) System.out.print(i+ " ");
        }
    }

    //Find the Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to n
    static void fibo(int n) {
        int fibo[] = new int[n];
        fibo[0] = 0;
        fibo[1] = 1;
        System.out.print(fibo[0]+" "+fibo[1]+" ");
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            fibo[i] = fibo[i - 1] + fibo[i - 2];
            if (n >= fibo[i]) {
                System.out.print(fibo[i]+ " ");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 40;
        System.out.println("The fibonacci list that smaller than " + k + " is:");
        fibo(k);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The prime list that smaller than " + k + " is:");
        allPrime(k);
    }

}
```

I tried to change my code to use ArrayList, but I was stuck at the fibo() method.

The output is:

```
The final intersection that are both fabonacci and prime is:
0 1true true true true true true true true 
The prime list that smaller than 40 is:
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37]
```

Why does it become a boolean type in my fibo list?

```
static void allPrime(int n) {
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
        if(IsPrime(i)) {
            primes.add(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(primes);
}

static void fibo(int n) {
    List <Integer> fibos = new ArrayList<>(n);
    int fibo[] = new int[n];
    fibo[0] = 0;
    fibo[1] = 1;
    System.out.print(fibo[0]+" " + fibo[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        fibo[i] = fibo[i - 1] + fibo[i - 2];
        if (n >= fibo[i]) {
           int in =fibo[i];
           System.out.print(fibos.add(in)+ " ");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make two methods return array or list then intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a data structure like a `HashSet` or `ArrayList` to do this, then find the intersection between them.

Solution using an `ArrayList`:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FiboAndPrime {


    static boolean IsPrime(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // Find all the prime numbers that are less than or equal to n
    static void allPrime(int n, List<Integer> prime_set ) {
        for(int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
            if(IsPrime(i)) System.out.print(i+ " ");
            prime_set.add(i);
        }
    }
    //Find the Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to n
    static void fibo(int n, List<Integer> fibo_set ) {
        int fibo[] = new int[n];
        fibo[0] = 0;
        fibo[1] = 1;
        System.out.print(fibo[0]+" "+fibo[1]+" ");
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            fibo[i] = fibo[i - 1] + fibo[i - 2];
            if (n >= fibo[i]) {
                System.out.print(fibo[i]+ " ");
                fibo_set.add(fibo[i]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 40;


        System.out.println("The fibonacci list that smaller than " + k + " is:");
        List<Integer> fibo_set = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        fibo_set.add(0);
        fibo_set.add(1);
        List<Integer> prime_set = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        fibo(k,fibo_set);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The prime list that smaller than " + k + " is:");
        allPrime(k,prime_set);

    fibo_set.retainAll(prime_set); // fibo_set now contains only elements in both sets

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("intersection between the fibo and prime set:");
    for (Integer intersection : fibo_set) {
    System.out.println(intersection);
    }

    }
}
```

Solution using a `HashSet`:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class FiboAndPrime {


    static boolean IsPrime(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // Find all the prime numbers that are less than or equal to n
    static void allPrime(int n, Set<Integer> prime_set ) {
        for(int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
            if(IsPrime(i)) System.out.print(i+ " ");
            prime_set.add(i);
        }
    }
    //Find the Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to n
    static void fibo(int n, Set<Integer> fibo_set ) {
        int fibo[] = new int[n];
        fibo[0] = 0;
        fibo[1] = 1;
        System.out.print(fibo[0]+" "+fibo[1]+" ");
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            fibo[i] = fibo[i - 1] + fibo[i - 2];
            if (n >= fibo[i]) {
                System.out.print(fibo[i]+ " ");
                fibo_set.add(fibo[i]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 40;


        System.out.println("The fibonacci list that smaller than " + k + " is:");
        Set<Integer> fibo_set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        fibo_set.add(0);
        fibo_set.add(1);
        Set<Integer> prime_set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        fibo(k,fibo_set);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The prime list that smaller than " + k + " is:");
        allPrime(k,prime_set);

    fibo_set.retainAll(prime_set); // fibo_set now contains only elements in both sets

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("intersection between the fibo and prime set:");
    for (Integer intersection : fibo_set) {
    System.out.println(intersection);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I've practice to change my code into arraylists type(in the bottom of my post), but I was stuck in the fibo() method, could you pleas kindly help me to figure out how to fix my code into arraylists? Thank you!!

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend using ArrayList unless you have a specific purpose as it is an inefficient data structure compared to a HashSet... but I modified my answer above to include it anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. I am not going to write code for you but i can suggest how you should do it. Rather than printing those fibonacci and primes under 40, you should store them in 2 different arrays and try to find what are common between them.But i think you are not familiar with arraylists and sets, i will suggest you another method.

When you find the fibonacci number under 40, check whether that number is prime or not. If it is, then print it or else you don't.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your recommendation without using arraylists or sets. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Why use `array` instead of `list` in java. You can simply achieve that by [`retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) as follows:

```
    List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>(primes);
    ret.retainAll(fibos);
```

For local test:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37));
    List<Integer> fibos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34));
    List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>(primes);
    ret.retainAll(fibos);
    System.out.println(ret);
}
```

The output will be:

```
[2, 3, 5, 13]
```

#### UPDATED

As requested by OP, I add this for reference:

```
static void fibo(int n) {
    List <Integer> fibos = new ArrayList<>(n);
    fibos.add(0);
    fibos.add(1);
    System.out.print(fibos.get(0) + "," + fibos.get(1));
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        int a = fibos.get(i-1) + fibos.get(i-2);
        if (a <= n) {
            fibos.add(a);
            System.out.print("," + a);
        } else break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I try to edit my code into ArrayList type in my post, but the fibo() method has some problem.. could you help me to fix it?

Comment: What have you tried? Accessing `list` you should use `list.get(i)` and `list.add(val)` while array `arr[i]` and `arr[i] = val`.

Comment: You can learn some basic tutorials for list operations here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/list-interface-java-examples/

Comment: I edit my code in the bottom of my post. I create a new arraylist called fibos, and use fibos.add(). But the output is true rather than integers (please see the bottom of the post)

Comment: @ShinYuWu Please mark the answer and upvote the solution if solves you problem, thank you ~